# Storyboard: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableCellBlueTextColor

Tags: ios, uikit, storyboard

I got a build error

> /Users/flamyoad/iOS-Projects/sample/sample/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard: Exception while running ibtool: [<IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration.IBNibUIColor 0x1122a31f0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableCellBlueTextColor.

for setting the View's background color to `Table Cell Blue Text Color`.

I'm still learning iOS development and I would like to understand the rationale behind Xcode for including it in the dropdown menu if it's not supposed to be used.

[image]

Comment: I just did a quick test by setting a view's background color to the same color. I then tried to build and I saw the same error. But when I then did another build, the error went away. Strange. Try doing a clean build and see if the error disappears.